# Problemas ao executar projeto Angular

Tags: angular

Criei um projeto em angular, para fins acadêmicos. E importei a biblioteca do PrimeNG, por possuir vários componentes bons.

Porém, quando eu vou executar o meu projeto, está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/primeng/components/multiselect/multiselect.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/scrolling' in 'C:\Users\gustavo.zaffani\IdeaProjects\gerenciamentoClient\node_modules\primeng\components\multiselect'
```

Alguém saberia dizer o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema, caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema, acessem esse link: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/6993 para darem uma olhada nas possibilidades de correção. No meu caso funcionou instalar o @angular/cdk.